# neo4j cypher - Match node where another specific node of the same type doesn't exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher

## Background

I have a neo4j database set up with the following nodes;

```
(:game)-[:teamscore]-(:team)
```

The 'game' node would contain an `id`, a `date` and a `name`

The 'team' node link would contain an `id`, a `teamname` and an `score`.

## Desired Outcome

I am looking to match nodes where `teamname` = "TeamA" but only where there isn't a linked node that exists with a different team for that 'game'.

#### (in plain English)

I want to return all nodes relating to a game where only 'TeamA' has scored (and not conceded).

## What I have so far

```
MATCH(g:game)-[:teamscore]-(t:team)
WHERE g.team = "TeamA"
RETURN g, t
```

I thought about adding some kind of `NOT (g)-[:teamscore]-(:team)` to the WHERE clause but I'm not sure how I could do this in a way which doesn't eliminate the node which I do want to match.

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a match team by name and then make sure only one team is linked to that game by specifying the number of `teamscore` relationships to that game is 1.

```
MATCH(g:game)-[:teamscore]-(t:team) 
WHERE t.teamname = "TeamA" AND size((g)-[:teamscore]-(:team))=1 
RETURN g, t
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if the assumption is correct, there can be more than one (teamA)-[:teamscore]->(game) for the same game.

If yes, then you can make sure that all connections from game to a team node are to teamA.

Given the following graph :

```
CREATE (g:Game {id: 1})-[:teamscore]->(:Team {id: 1, name: "TeamA"})
CREATE (g)-[:teamscore]->(:Team {id:2, name: "TeamA"})
CREATE (g)-[:teamscore]->(:Team {id:3, name: "TeamA"})
CREATE (g2:Game {id: 2})-[:teamscore]->(:Team {name: "TeamA"})
CREATE (g2)-[:teamscore]->(:Team {name: "TeamB"})
```

You can use pattern comprehensions and the `ALL` predicate :

```
MATCH (n:Game)
WHERE ALL(x IN [(n)-[:teamscore]->(t) | t.name] WHERE x = "TeamA")
RETURN n
```

It will return Game with id 1